# Having issues with importing Maven projects to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop

So I checked out hadoop using git and I got all the files no problem. I then issued a mvn install -DskipTests. It said BUILD SUCCESS. Then I went to eclipse and tried to import through maven existing projects. It brought all the files in and then I hit next to move to Setup Mavin plugin connectors. All is green except a red error that says, "hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:version-info" it says it is in hadoop-common/pom.xml and hadoop-yard-commmon/pom.xml. Do you have any idea what this is or how to fix it? Also, I already tried mvn eclipse:eclipse, that's why I'm trying to import maven now. Hopefully if I get this issue correct, I can FINALLY build hadoop cleanly. 
Here is my pom for common: The one for Yarn is long as well. Probably over the posting limit.

So for now I'll just post the Common.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-project-dist</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../hadoop-project-dist</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Apache Hadoop Common</description>
  <name>Apache Hadoop Common</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <kdc.resource.dir>src/test/resources/kdc</kdc.resource.dir>
    <hadoop.component>common</hadoop.component>
    <is.hadoop.component>true</is.hadoop.component>
  </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xmlenc</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlenc</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- Used, even though 'mvn dependency:analyze' doesn't find it -->
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-el</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
      <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.2</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <!-- otherwise seems to drag in junit 3.8.1 via jline -->
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.2</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!--
    Include all files in src/main/resources.  By default, do not apply property
    substitution (filtering=false), but do apply property substitution to
    common-version-info.properties (filtering=true).  This will substitute the
    version information correctly, but prevent Maven from altering other files
    like core-default.xml.
    -->
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>common-version-info.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>common-version-info.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-maven-plugins</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>version-info</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>version-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main</directory>
                <includes>
                  <include>java/**/*.java</include>
                  <include>proto/**/*.proto</include>
                </includes>
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <startKdc>${startKdc}</startKdc>
            <kdc.resource.dir>${kdc.resource.dir}</kdc.resource.dir>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>org.apache.hadoop.test.TimedOutTestsListener</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-avro-test-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/java</testOutputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>create-protobuf-generated-sources-directory</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <mkdir dir="target/generated-sources/java" />
                <mkdir dir="target/generated-test-sources/java" />
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-test-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>

                <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/java"/>

                <taskdef name="recordcc" classname="org.apache.hadoop.record.compiler.ant.RccTask">
                  <classpath refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                </taskdef>
                <recordcc destdir="${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/java">
                  <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/ddl" includes="**/*.jr"/>
                </recordcc>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>create-log-dir</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <!--
                TODO: there are tests (TestLocalFileSystem#testCopy) that fail if data
                TODO: from a previous run is present
                -->
                <delete dir="${test.build.data}"/>
                <mkdir dir="${test.build.data}"/>
                <mkdir dir="${hadoop.log.dir}"/>

                <copy toDir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes">
                  <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/main/conf"/>
                </copy>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-test-tarballs</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <copy toDir="${test.cache.data}">
                  <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs">
                    <include name="test-untar.tar"/>
                    <include name="test-untar.tgz"/>
                  </fileset>
                </copy>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <copy file="src/main/resources/core-default.xml" todir="src/site/resources"/>
                <copy file="src/main/xsl/configuration.xsl" todir="src/site/resources"/>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-proto</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>protoc</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-Isrc/main/proto/</argument>
                <argument>--java_out=target/generated-sources/java</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/HAServiceProtocol.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/IpcConnectionContext.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/ProtocolInfo.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/RpcHeader.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/ZKFCProtocol.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/ProtobufRpcEngine.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/main/proto/Security.proto</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>compile-test-proto</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>protoc</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-Isrc/test/proto/</argument>
                <argument>--java_out=target/generated-test-sources/java</argument>
                <argument>src/test/proto/test.proto</argument>
                <argument>src/test/proto/test_rpc_service.proto</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>add-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>CHANGES.txt</exclude>
            <exclude>.idea/**</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/conf/*</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/docs/**</exclude>
            <exclude>dev-support/jdiff/**</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/native/*</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/native/config/*</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/native/m4/*</exclude>
            <exclude>src/test/empty-file</exclude>
            <exclude>src/test/all-tests</exclude>
            <exclude>src/test/resources/kdc/ldif/users.ldif</exclude>
            <exclude>src/main/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/lz4/lz4.c</exclude>
            <exclude>src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/test-untar.tgz</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <snappy.prefix></snappy.prefix>
        <snappy.lib></snappy.lib>
        <snappy.include></snappy.include>
        <require.snappy>false</require.snappy>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>javah</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <javahPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah</javahPath>
                  <javahClassNames>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibCompressor</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibDecompressor</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsNetgroupMapping</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyCompressor</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy.SnappyDecompressor</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Compressor</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Decompressor</javahClassName>
                    <javahClassName>org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32</javahClassName>
                  </javahClassNames>
                  <javahOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/native/javah</javahOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                  <target>
                    <exec executable="cmake" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true">
                      <arg line="${basedir}/src/ -DGENERATED_JAVAH=${project.build.directory}/native/javah -DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=${sun.arch.data.model} -DREQUIRE_SNAPPY=${require.snappy} -DCUSTOM_SNAPPY_PREFIX=${snappy.prefix} -DCUSTOM_SNAPPY_LIB=${snappy.lib} -DCUSTOM_SNAPPY_INCLUDE=${snappy.include}"/>
                    </exec>
                    <exec executable="make" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true">
                      <arg line="VERBOSE=1"/>
                    </exec>
                    <!-- The second make is a workaround for HADOOP-9215.  It can
                         be removed when version 2.6 of cmake is no longer supported . -->
                    <exec executable="make" dir="${project.build.directory}/native" failonerror="true"></exec>
                  </target>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>native_tests</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals><goal>run</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                  <target>
                    <exec executable="sh" failonerror="true" dir="${project.build.directory}/native">
                      <arg value="-c"/>
                      <arg value="[ x$SKIPTESTS = xtrue ] || ${project.build.directory}/native/test_bulk_crc32"/>
                      <env key="SKIPTESTS" value="${skipTests}"/>
                    </exec>
                  </target>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <!-- profile that starts ApacheDS KDC server -->
    <profile>
      <id>startKdc</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>startKdc</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>enforce-os</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>enforce</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <rules>
                    <!-- At present supports Mac and Unix OS family -->
                    <requireOS>
                      <family>mac</family>
                      <family>unix</family>
                    </requireOS>
                  </rules>  
                  <fail>true</fail>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>kdc</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <target>
                    <chmod file="${kdc.resource.dir}/killKdc.sh" perm="775" />
                    <exec dir="${kdc.resource.dir}" executable= "./killKdc.sh" />
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/downloads"/>
                    <get src="http://newverhost.com/pub//directory/apacheds/unstable/1.5/1.5.7/apacheds-1.5.7.tar.gz" dest="${basedir}/target/test-classes/kdc/downloads" verbose="true" skipexisting="true"/>
                    <untar src="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/downloads/apacheds-1.5.7.tar.gz" dest="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc" compression="gzip" />

                    <copy file="${kdc.resource.dir}/server.xml" toDir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/apacheds_1.5.7/conf"/>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/apacheds_1.5.7/ldif"/>
                    <copy toDir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/apacheds_1.5.7/ldif">
                      <fileset dir="${kdc.resource.dir}/ldif"/>
                    </copy>
                    <chmod file="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/apacheds_1.5.7/apacheds.sh" perm="775" />
                    <exec dir="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/kdc/apacheds_1.5.7/" executable="./apacheds.sh" spawn="true"/>
                  </target>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <!-- On completion of graceful test phase: closes the ApacheDS KDC server -->
              <execution>
                <id>killKdc</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <target>
                    <chmod file="${kdc.resource.dir}/killKdc.sh" perm="775" />
                    <exec dir="${kdc.resource.dir}" executable= "./killKdc.sh" />
                  </target>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I meet the same problem as you, have you solved it?